tmap is mapping non-"value" numbers from a raster
I have images from a FLIR camera that I'm trying to examine as rasters in R. When I copy the image here: 
right-click and 'Save As', the weird behavior doesn't happen. So I've stuck an example image and the code below in a GitHub repository: https://github.com/kjfuller06/QuestionData
Here's the problem: when I plot the image using tmap, it shows what I want. The values range from 0 to 255 and the plot resembles the image: 
When I use the base R function plot(), or when I try to interact with the 'values' in the raster, they look nothing like the tmap plot or the photo when opened with any other software: 
I've encountered some weird behavior with tmap before, when plotting variables were stored in an attributes table. But I can't find anything like that when I look at attributes(). What in the heck is tmap plotting and how do I access these numbers?
Here's the code I used to generate the last two images:
library(raster)
library(tmap)

setwd("C:/budkill/data")
r1 = raster("FLIR0031.jpg")

tm_shape(r1) + tm_raster()
plot(r1)

head(values(r1))
attributes(r1)


You need to expand the pallete.

Not sure I understand how that would help. The values are completely different.
